# Get Name of Controller from ActionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing an ActionFilter and would like to have a more type-safe way to use RedirectToRouteResult. While investigating this, I wondered if there was a way to get the name (as a string) of any of my controllers. So for example, I would like to get "Home" from my HomeController, or "Admin" from my Admin controller. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 3):

From a filter context you can get the controller name by using:

```
public class MyFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //That will give you "HomeController"
        var controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;

        //You can remove the "Controller" part, by replacing it with an empty string, like:
        var justTheController = controllerName.Replace("Controller", string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: `filterContext.Controller` wiill directly give you the Controller name isint ?

Comment: Not exactly. It will give you the `Controller` object Then you could get the name by `filterContext.Controller.GetType().Name`. It also works.

Comment: this will not work if controler name is for  example 'ControllerXXXController'. It will remove both substrings

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this.  You know you can substitute typeof by GetType on instance variable. if you have HomeController instance homeCtrl....you can do `homeCtrl.GetType`

```
  var fullName= typeof(HomeController).Name;
  var partialName = fullName.Remove(fullName.IndexOf("Controller"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are ways to get the controller name :

1. `filterContext.Controller` will give you an object from where you
   can deduce the controller name as
   *`filterContext.Controller.GetType().Name`*
2. You always have the `controller` in the route values and  can deduce as `Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values("controller").ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

Write extension method

```
public static class ControllerStringExtension
{
    private const string ControllerString = "Controller";
    public static string Short(this string value)
    {
        if (value.EndsWith(ControllerString))
        {   
            //Remove 'Controller' from end of value name.             
            return value.Remove(value.Length - ControllerString.Length);
        }
        throw new ApplicationException("Should be used only for Controller names.");
    }
}
```

than use: *Redirect to 'home' controler and 'index' action.*

```
 public RedirectToRouteResult Something()
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), nameof(HomeController).Short());
    }
```